# How to convert datetime to seconds vb.net

Tags: vb.net, api, datetime, youtube, type-conversion

I want to get number of seconds FROM the time of my video was started broadcasting.
I can get `actualStartTime` using youtube API :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id=WAGNjrjJ_hg&key="api_key"

{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "cNrmxjhTwAaA7H3Gt42xWf1njbU",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "PQbK4Z_LITQoQh3vsdycdCNvD-E",
      "id": "WAGNjrjJ_hg",
      "liveStreamingDetails": {
        "actualStartTime": "2020-12-22T05:29:43Z",
        "scheduledStartTime": "2020-12-22T05:26:58Z",
        "concurrentViewers": "16",
        "activeLiveChatId": "Cg0KC1dBR05qcmpKX2hnKicKGFVDX2NyM3RPa2dyLWwwVzlNUm1QUWJHQRILV0FHTmpyakpfaGc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

But the format `actualStartTime": "2020-12-22T05:29:43Z"`

What I'm trying to do is press the button and convert `actualStartTime` formate against the current request `datetime` to seconds and show it in my textbox so I can see how long my stream is already running, by comparing `actualStartTime` against the current request `datetime` and divide the time between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below snippet

```
#PARSE THE TIME FROM STRING FORMAT TO REGULAR DATETIME OBJECT
Dim date1 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2020-12-22T05:29:43Z")

#CURRENT DATETIME
Dim date2 As DateTime = Now

#GET TIMESPAN OBJECT AFTER SUBTRACTING THE DATETIME OBJECTS
Dim interval As TimeSpan = date2 - date1

#GET THE TIME DIFFERENCE IN SECONDS (YOU CAN GET IN HOURS OR MINUTES ALSO)
Dim seconds As Long = interval.TotalSeconds
```

Use `TotalMinutes` for minutes, `TotalHours` for hours.